# Expand file system

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, fdisk

I found I need more disc space in my Ubuntu system that runs on VMware virtual machine. I expanded disc in Virtual Machine settings and got message:

```
The disk was successfully expanded. You must repartition the disk and expand the file systems from within the guest operating system.
```

How to expand file system from inside operating system?

[image]

Comment: no, this answer is about VitualBox, and I use Vmware

Comment: In Ubuntu, run sudo parted on your root, and expand the partition.  parted may be smart enough to expand the filesystem when you do this. Othersize (install and) run resize2fs yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to resize partition on working system?

Comment: parted claims to be able to do this, when the expansion is added to the "end" of the partition.  see man parted for details.